# VBA excel 2007, ComboBox "Permission Denied"

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I'm a beginner with VBA, I'm developing a macro on excel 2007 and I'm having some problems with the ComboBox. Anywhere I try to add items i always get the error 70 "Permission Denied". What is my mistake? 
Below you can find my simple code

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim pic As IPictureDisp

Set pic = UserForm1.Image1.Picture

'stdole.SavePicture pic, "ciao"
Call SavePicture(pic, "ciao.jpg")
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
   Dim MyChart As Chart
   Dim ChartData As Range
   Dim ChartName As String
   ChartName = "ANCONA"
   Set ChartData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A9")
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  'UserForm1.Image4.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\rfori\Desktop\PROGETTO 
   MARTINA\parto_trig.jpg")


'
  Set MyChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlXYScatterLines).Chart
  With MyChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

        .Name = ChartName
        .Values = ChartData
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B9")
   End With

   Dim imageName As String
   imageName = "prova.jpg"
   MyChart.Export Filename:=imageName, FilterName:="jpg"

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   UserForm1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("prova.jpg")
  'MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = ChartName
  'MyChart.SetSourceData Source:=ChartData
End Sub



Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
  ComboBox1.AddItem "ciao"
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   ComboBox1.AddItem "ciao"
 With Me
  .StartUpPosition = 1
  .Width = MultiPage1.Width
  .Height = MultiPage1.Height
  .Left = Application.Left - (Application.Width * 0.85) \ 2
  .Top = Application.Top - (Application.Height * 0.85) \ 2
 End With

  myarray1 = Array("Ancona", "Milano", "Palermo")

  For x = 0 To 2

  'ComboBox1.AddItem myarray1(x)
  Next x
End Sub

Sub window_sizer()
 With ActiveWindow
  .WindowState = xlNormal`enter code here`
  .Height = 75
  .Width = 125
  .ScrollColumn = 1
  .ScrollRow = 1
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995598/vba-combobox-additem-and-getting-a-runtime-error-70) before post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA combobox additem and getting a runtime error 70](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995598/vba-combobox-additem-and-getting-a-runtime-error-70)

Comment: you can amso populate a combobox directly from the array : ´me.combobox1.list = myarray1´

Comment: Thank you all! I apologize for asking a duplicate question, I'm new I made a research but I didn't find the similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem before as described in [Combobox additem permission denied error no.70](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/140017-combobox-additem-permission-denied-error-no-70)
. 
Make sure that the property `ListFillRange` is empty.