# VBA clear ActiveX combobox list

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, activex

How to clear Excel ActiveX ComboBox list with VBA. I expected this code would work:

```
Sheet1.OLEObjects(1).Clear
```

but it raises

> runtime error object doesn't support this property or method.

I am puzzled because this works:

```
Sheet1.OLEObjects(1).Name
```

returning the name `TempCombo`.

I still fail when I try this:

```
Sheet1.TempCombo.Clear
```

It returns error:

> Runtime error Unspecified error.

What else should I check?

Comment: I think it must be `Sheet1.OLEObjects(1).Object.Clear`. But also `Sheet1.TempCombo.Clear` works for me without throwing an error. `Sheet1.TempCombo.List = Array()` is another way to remove all items from the list. • I cannot reproduce your issue. There must be something else causing this error.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ you are right! .Clear should actually work. Did you check if you're sheet/combobox -name is correct?

Comment: @J.schmidt Sheet name must be correct otherwise `Sheet1.OLEObjects(1).Name` would not give the correct name. Therefore also the ComboBox name is proof.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I have found out that `Sheet1.TempCombo.Clear` will fail unless the property `.ListFillRange = ""`. This is experienced by other users https://stackoverflow.com/a/51425477/1903793

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin Strange it worked for me. But I never used the  `.ListFillRange` in my test. I added items with `TempCombo.AddItem "test"`. So thanks for the follow up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to clear the ActiveX ComboBox list, you may try something like this...

```
Sheet1.OLEObjects(1).ListFillRange = ""
```

Or more precisely this...

```
If TypeName(Sheet1.OLEObjects(1).Object) = "ComboBox" Then
    Sheet1.OLEObjects(1).ListFillRange = ""
End If
```

Comment: This works. However what is surprising is that `Sheet1.OLEObjects(1).Object.Clear` doesn't raise error after `Sheet1.OLEObjects(1).ListFillRange = ""`

Comment: Well, that's interesting! Glad it worked as desired. Please take a minute to mark your question as Solved by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the combobox has a name, you can just refer to the name. Like

```
With mySheet
    .cbMyComboBox.ListFillRange = vbNullString
End with
```